# Asp.net button is not firing event

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having an issue with the asp.net button. It is not firing event. I tried setting causes validation to false and removing the java script and validation but it still doesn't work.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Save" onclick="Button2_Click" />


protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    std.AddGuardianInfo(
        Convert.ToInt16(DropDownList1.SelectedValue), 
        TextBox6.Text, 
        TextBox7.Text, 
        TextBox8.Text, 
        TextBox9.Text, 
        TextBox10.Text);
    Response.Redirect("Std_FeeInfo.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Please try to add only the relevant part of your code in future questions.

Comment: could you please remove the irrelevant codes from your question? and indent the relevant code properly, then you will get better response

Comment: Try my solution !! This little bit of code we can provide this much of information.!!

Answer (score 1):

Change `onclick` to `OnClick` in the markup of the `asp:button`. so the markup will be like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
```

And an important advise for you: **Use [`css`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/) for styling and arranging elements in your page, giving space using a sequence of `&nbsp;` will not be a good design**

Comment: @Rabiya, define "isn't working". Do you have errors in the browser console? Is the request sent to the server? Do you have an Exception on the server? It isn't working, we understand that. But HOW?

Comment: The button is not throwing any exception or error. It is not responding when it is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

> You want to check this steps.

- @rabiya are you copied this code in some where else ? Then just remove it and double click on your asp button.
- If you are using updatepanel on onclick event, this may happen.So Use '`EnableEventValidation="false"`'

**Example :**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" EnableEventValidation="false"  CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>
```